# AngularJS Website - Full or Partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I would like to build a new web site using AngularJS. The idea is to build a server side API with Ruby on Rails that serve Json to a front-end AngularJS.

My question is: **Is it better to create a full AngluarJS front-end or a standard ruby on rails front-end with some Angular ?**

I know Angular can handle routing so a full application is possible but it looks like the default behavior is for single page app.

For example I wonder if it's not a problem to make some change in an angular page 1 that should modify a page 2. This page 2 will not be updated until an action is taken on the page or the user reload the page.

Is there something wrong in my approach ? What do you advise ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have personally done variations of a number of angular apps, varying from SPA with 50K+ views to simply using angular as an extension of basic javascript for useful testing and modularization.

The answer to your question isn't actually all that technical but more has to do with the nature of your application and team (You're essentially trying to pick what type of screwdriver to use). As what you're trying to do is feasible on both the client and server side.

Important questions to ask:

1. Is your team more comfortable in Rails or Angular
2. How dynamic are your web pages expected to be
3. What browsers are you supporting
4. Is there a requirement for data latency and communication with the server
5. Are you also going to be reusing the server API for other applications

These questions will drive you towards use of Angular or Rails or the combination of the technologies to find the balance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So in your opinion a full front-end AngularJS is not a problem event if the application is multipage and it won't be a problem if it become bigger in the future. The main idea is to reuse the API for other system yes, so I want it independant from the front.

Comment: That's correct. A properly designed SPA with optimizations for delivery can very easily scale to hundreds of "pages", and views.  If you go down that path, please use require and their bundling and minification tools, otherwise you'll have terrible performance as the app grows.

Comment: Do you have any links regarding those "require and their bundling and minification tools" ?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/  Its a dependency mapper between javascript files. It also will do bundling and minification for you. On my last project it collapsed 100+ files into 3 and went from 3MB to 40KB. Without it the project would have been undeliverable.

Answer (score 0):

The routing mechanism in angular is only within a single window object.

If you have two windows you will have two angular applications. If you want to communicate between the windows object angular does not provide any special mechanism further than standard HTML and javascript.

I don't know what is the better approach for you, that depends in your business requirements and constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
What do you mean by within a single window object ? I can have a menu with multiple different pages (list A, list B for example) all in the same Angular app. I'll probably have one controller by "page" but just one Angular app. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes you have as many controllers as you want and you can navigate between them, but all the navigation happens within the same window object that is why it is called Single page application, because the whole application lives in the same web page. Each Angular view is contained usually in a div or section tag but not in its own web page

Comment: Alright, I get it. So is it quickly a mess to share informations or trigger events between controllers ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be. you can share information between controllers primary by passing arguments in the query string or using an Angular service. And with events out of the box Angular provides a mechanism: $rootScope.$emit, $rootScope.$broadcast, $rootScope.$on But you can easily use other like for example [pubsubjs](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS )